# How do I compare file names in two directories in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

Right now, this is what my code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

Dir1=$1
Dir2=$2

for file1 in $Dir1/*; do
    for file2 in $Dir2/*; do
        if [[ $file1 == $file2 ]]; then
            echo "$file1 is contained in both directories"
        fi
    done
done
```

I am trying to compare the file names of the two directories entered and say that the file is in both directories if the filename matches.
When I try to run it though, nothing is echo-ed even though I have the same file in both directories.

Answer (score 62):

Files that are in both `Dir1` and `Dir2`:

```
find "$Dir1/" "$Dir2/" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d
```

Files that are in `Dir1` but not in `Dir2`:

```
find "$Dir1/" "$Dir2/" "$Dir2/" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -u
```

Files that are in `Dir2` but not in `Dir1`:

```
find "$Dir1/" "$Dir1/" "$Dir2/" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: this is very elegant solution on account of the simple logic of printing all files in one of the directories twice, then sorting them, so that they are filtered by uniq later. could not find the documentation on %P for printf, would be helpful if you could share a link?

Comment: @AnirtakVarma, thank you. Sorry didn't see you comment until now. Man page for [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) covers it under `-printf` section. It says: `%P File's name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed`

Comment: I had a special case where I wanted to compare Dir1 and Dir2, but Dir2 is a subfolder of Dir1. In that case I needed to exclude the output of Dir2 in Dir1.   This is what I used to find Files that are in Dir1 but not in Dir2: `(find . -printf '%P\n' | grep -v Dir2  && find Dir2/ -printf '%P\n' && find Dir2/ -printf '%P\n') | sort | uniq -u` It assumes I am already inside Dir1.

Comment: Really cool way, allows to find files with ignoring paths. Just need to use %f for printf instead of %P.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know what's common to two directories then this is another way with much less coding.

```
#!/bin/bash

comm -12 <(ls -F $1) <(ls -F $2)
```

See `man comm` for more information about the `comm` utility.

Comment: I was going to post similar answer with `find` instead of `ls`. But this approach should also work if there are no sub-directories which need to be compared. For further fine tuning, you may consider adding `-F` flag to `ls`..

Comment: This approach fails (or at least is unclear) if filenames contain newlines.  Try running `touch red blue red$'\n'white` in two directories and comparing them.

Comment: @ghoti, I just tested with your `touch` command and it still worked with a file name containing a newline, so I'm not sure why you say this approach fails.  Did you actually test it yourself?

Comment: @anishsane, yes using `find` has its advantages however since the OP had no mention or coding of recursion I chose to keep it simple.

Comment: @ghoti's comment is correct. [`parsing ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (or `find` for that matter) is discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you're comparing variables that contain the directory prefix. Just remove the prefix before comparing:

```
name1=${file1##*/}
name2=${file2##*/}
if [[ $name1 == $name2 ]]; then
    echo "$name1 exists in both directories"
fi
```

Also, nested loops seems like an inefficient way to do this. You just need to get the filenames from one directory, and use a simple file existence check for the other directory.

```
for file in $Dir1/*; do
    name=${file##*/}
    if [[ -f $Dir2/$name ]]; then
        echo "$name exists in both directories"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it worked:

```
DIR1=$(ls dir1)
DIR2=$(ls dir2)

for i in $DIR1; do
    for j in $DIR2; do
        if [[ $i == $j ]]; then
            echo "$i == $j"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Fails on filenames with special characters.  Please see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison fails because `Dir1/foo` is not the same as `Dir2/foo`.  Instead, if you change to one directory, your `*` will expand to just the filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash

Dir1="$1"
Dir2="$2"

if ! cd "$Dir1"; then
  echo "ERROR: Couldn't find directory $Dir1" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [[ ! "$Dir2" =~ ^/ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: Second directory must be a full path." >&2
  exit 1
fi

for file1 in *; do
    if [ -f "$Dir2/$file1" ]; then
        echo "$file1 is contained in both directories"
    fi
done
```

Note that this only matches file *names*.  If you want to make sure it's really the same file, you should use [`cmp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cmp) to compare them.